# Value not changing after if statement in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

Hi I want to check if a date already exists in my db but my code is not changing the value to false here is my code

```
$query_db = $conn->prepare('SELECT DATE(dvanaf) AS DatumVanaf, DATE(dtot) AS DatumTot, actief
                            FROM beschikbaarheid WHERE DID = :DID AND actief = 1');
$query_db->bindParam(':DID', $did, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_db->execute();

$begin = new DateTime( $dvanaf );
$end = new DateTime( $dtot );
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

//Check if date already exists in db
foreach($daterange as $date){
  while ($datum = $query_db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    if($datum['DatumVanaf'] == $date->format("d-m-Y")) 
    {//Change datescheck to false if date exists
        $datesCheck = false; 
        break;
    }
  }
}

echo $datesCheck;
die();
```

When I run the code and echo $datesCheck it stays on 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only checking the first date in the range. The `while()` loop in the first iteration of the `for` loop will fetch all the rows from the query. Other iterations won't have anything left in the query results, so the `while` loop will terminate immediately.

You should put the query results in an array and loop through that instead.

Another problem is that dates returned by the DB are in the format `Y-m-d`, not `d-m-Y`.

```
$query_results = $query_db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    foreach ($query_results as $datum) {
        if($datum['DatumVanaf'] == $date->format("Y-m-d")) 
        {//Change datescheck to false if date exists
            $datesCheck = false; 
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```

But looping through the dates is a silly way to do this. You can just check whether the date is between `$begin` and `$end`:

```
$begin_str = $begin->format("Y-m-d");
$end_str = $end->format("Y-m-d");
while ($datum = $query_db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($datum['DatumVanaf'] >= $begin_str && $datum['DatumVanaf'] <= $end_str) {
        $datesCheck = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Even better would be to put the check in the query itself.

```
$query_db = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
                            FROM beschikbaarheid 
                            WHERE DID = :DID AND actief = 1
                            AND DatumVanaf BETWEEN :begin AND :end');
$query_db->bindParam(':DID', $did, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_db->bindValue(':begin', $begin->format("Y-m-d 0:0:0"));
$query_db->bindValue(':end', $end->format("Y-m-d 23:59:59"));
$query_db->execute();
$datum = $query_db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$datesCheck = $datum['count'] > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change date format in condition as below

`(if($datum['DatumVanaf'] == $date->format("d-m-Y")) )`

**to**

```
if($datum['DatumVanaf'] == $date->format("**Y-m-d**"))
```